# How launch all maps app android intent

Tags: android, maps

I want to open all the maps app through intent.

I tried it, and the app crashes, the intent doesn't open

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent("android.intent.category.APP_MAPS");
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: describe "it doesn't work" please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Try this.